# Is it possible to check for text in a GUI button?

Tags: java, button

This is a really simple code where when I click a button, the text on the button becomes "..."  which is a string variable called `move`.

What I'm trying to figure out is if it is possible to check the text of a button in the `if (e.getSource()==)` command.

```
JButton [] button;
String move="...";

button =new JButton[25];
for (int a=0;a<25;a++)
{
    button[a]=new JButton();
    p1.add(button[a]); 
    button[a].addActionListener(this);
}   

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    for (int a=0; a<25;a++)
    {
        if (e.getSource()==button[a])
        {
          button[a].setText(move);
        }
    }
}
```

So after the code above, a button will have the text "..." on it. Now what I want for the next `if (e.getSource()==)` command is: if the button I click has the text (`move`), run the code.

I tried hundreds of random codes to see if they'll work but no luck:

sort of like this:

`if (e.getSource()==button[a].text(move))`

OR

`if (e.getSource()==button[a].getText.equals(move))`

```
if (The button i click has the text (move) it will run this code)
{
    button[a].setBackground(Color.GREEN); 
}
```

I'm fairly new to programming and I need this for my Checkers game.
Is it possible to do what I am asking for?

Answer (score 1):

String comparison in Java should be done with .equals() not ==.

Comment: If you look carefully at the post you'll see this isn't the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The examples you have checking the source against the button text doesn't make a lot of sense. You're adding an action listener on the button not a field of the button. Additionally, `getSource` returns an `Object` so if you need to get to any of its member values you'll need to cast it to the type it should be. In your case you're returned an `Object` with an *actual* type `JButton`.

```
JButton button = new JButton("Hello");
button.addActionListener((e) -> System.out.println(
        e.getSource() instanceof JButton
));
button.doClick();
```

> true

So, given a button you can get the text like so:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Hello");
button.addActionListener((e) -> System.out.println(
    ((JButton)e.getSource()).getText()
));
button.doClick();
```

> Hello

So, to check `move` against it would be like so:

```
String move = "Howdy";
JButton button = new JButton("Hello");
button.addActionListener((e) -> System.out.println(
    ((JButton) e.getSource()).getText().equals(move)
));
button.doClick();
```

> false

Another thing to note is when you get an instance of a button through `getSource` you don't need to find that instance in the array before using it; it's returned to you via the action listener. For example, run this code:

```
JButton[] buttons = new JButton[10];
Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
String newText = "New";
for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; ++i) {
    buttons[i] = new JButton(String.valueOf(r.nextInt()));
    buttons[i].addActionListener((e) -> ((JButton)e.getSource()).setText(newText + " " + r.nextInt()));
}
Arrays.stream(buttons).forEach(b -> {
    System.out.println(b.getText());
    b.doClick();
    System.out.println(b.getText());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean like this:

```
if (e.getSource() == button[a]) {
    if (button[a].getText().equals(move)) {
        // do some logic here
        button[a].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    }
}
```